# Js Vanilla dynamic url + nesting anchor and preventdefault

Tags: javascript, ajax, preventdefault

How to preventdefault anchor that has child element. I use event delegate click since the link is set dynamically.

When user click, I have to check if it has `data-applink` in the anchor, in this case I traverse using `closest` to find its parent (since click event will detect child element, not the anchor).

After I obtain the parent, then I add click event and preventdefault it. But somehow it does not work.

Please help, any idea?

```js
//simulate ajax
setTimeout(()=> {
  const anchor = document.querySelectorAll('.anchor')[0];
  anchor.setAttribute("href", "http://www.google.com");
  anchor.setAttribute("data-applink", "app://link.id");
},800);

const checkNesting = (selector, event, callback) => {
  let elem = event.target;
  if (elem.matches(selector)) {
     callback(elem);
  }else{
     elem = event.target.closest(selector);
    if (elem) {
      // console.log(elem);
       callback(elem);
    }
  }
 

}
document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  checkNesting('*[data-applink]', event, (el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
       ev.preventDefault();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="anchor">
  <button>Click Here</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    el.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
       ev.preventDefault();
    });
```

My best guess is that the above event listener starts working at the next click event, not the current one. If anyone can provide explanation, I am very appreciated.

To solve your problem, you can apply `preventDefault` to the current `event`:

```js
//simulate ajax
setTimeout(()=> {
  const anchor = document.querySelectorAll('.anchor')[0];
  anchor.setAttribute("href", "https://www.google.com");
  anchor.setAttribute("data-applink", "app://link.id");
},800);

const checkNesting = (selector, event, callback) => {
  let elem = event.target;
  if (elem.matches(selector)) {
     return true
  }
  elem = event.target.closest(selector);
  if (elem) {
    // console.log(elem);
     return true
  }
  return false
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (checkNesting('*[data-applink]', event)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="anchor">
  <button onClick="alert('I am working fine and bubbling up is cancelled')">Click Here</button>
</a>

<a href="https://www.google.com">
<button onClick="alert('I allow bubbling up')">Click me too</button>
</a>
```

Comment: You are right, I shouldn't add click event again inside document click delegation, your answer works so the key is just using return boolean, so there is no need to callback? I use callback because I need to do something about the elem (or matched parent elem). I guess I just create another function instead of callback function?

Comment: @Ardeus yes, that should be the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
(() => {
  const anchor = document.querySelector('#anchor');

  setTimeout(()=> {
    anchor.setAttribute("href", "http://www.google.com");
    anchor.setAttribute("data-applink", "app://link.id");
  }, 800);

  anchor.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('prevented');
  });
})();
```

I'm not quite sure but it seems to me that 'preventDefault' is quite overcomplicated, but this one should work fine.